# C# constructor overload + explicit cast = .dll reference missing

Tags: c#, .net, casting, constructor, overloading

Simplified classes are below. Every namespace is in seperate .cproj. I have "B is defined in an assembly that is not referenced" problem when building z.exe.

I added ctor A(string s) because I don't want to include y.dll in every z (I have a lot of z). How to make this work with no mess?

One way is to add another argument in A(B b) or A(string s) so that they have different number of arguments but this is not nice to me.

```
    //namespace x
    using y;
    public class A
    {
        public A(string s)
        public A(B b)
    }

    //namespace y
    public class B
    {
        public static explicit operator B(string s)
    }

    //namesapce z
    using x;
    public class C
    {
        void M()
        {
            string s = "";
            A(s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried partial classes?

Comment: @elyashiv Not sure how would partial class help. Can you please explain more about your idea?

Comment: declare `A` as partial, and `declare A(B b)` in `y.dll`.

Comment: @elyashiv, you can't split the implementation of a class across multiple assemblies using a partial class.  Only across multiple source files that compile to the same assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know to achieve this is to make the second A constructor internal:

```
//namespace x     
public class A     
{         
    public A(string s)         
    internal A(B b)     
}
```

If you have other assemblies that need to use this constructor; you could consider using `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute.

Comment: This is a nice trick, didn't know that this is possible. I'll just have to see how many friends I have and decide is this better or dummy parameter for those who are not my friends ;)

Comment: @watbywbarif, yes, it's probably best to limit it to a very few close friends :)  If you have more than a few, you might want to reconsider your design - possibly move B into the same assembly as A.

Answer (score 1):

Why not derive another class from A which then hides the unwanted constructor?

```
public class ADerived : A
{
    public ADerived(string s) : base (s)
    {
    }
}
```

and then use `ADerived` from namespace / assembly z?

Comment: This is one way for sure, but as I will have many A also this is unpractical.

Answer (score 1):

Your class A references B (as a constructor parameter) so anything that use class A will also need to know class B to build.

By the way, for your code to build, there's a missing `using y;` before the A class declaration.

Comment: Not true when constructors have different count of parameters. Tried that and no reference to B needed in z. Thanks for using y!

Comment: Right, it does build in this case~

Comment: It would be so cool if it would also build with extra dummy argument which has default value, but that is not working ;(